# Implementing Multiple selection drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement Multiple selection drag and drop, single selection works ok but I am struggling with multiple selection

I am using the jquery.rowselector.min.js to enable multiple selection but in the 'onDragStart' method I cannot see how to add the multiple rows as it seems to be limited to one entry per mime type.

This is the SINGLE event handler:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("orderId", ev.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

And this is what I have for MULTI which does list the selected id's:

```
function dragMulti(ev) {

    $('#orderTable').selectedrows().each( function( index, order ) {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
    alert("Selected ID : " + id )
    })
}
```

Looking at various google searches there appears to be a js file that allows multiple setData calls using indices eg:
dataTransfer.mozSetDataAt(...)

but I cannot find it

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Just checked, the moz... methods only apply to Firefox so not a viable option, any other suggestions gratefully received

Comment: The simplest answer is to concatenate the list of ID's into a single string and pass that as an argument in the setData method of the SINGLE event handler but, is there a more elegant way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

I started by using the row-selector.js package to enable the multi row selection and then found all elements which had their checked attribute set to produce a concatenated list